# Get DateTimeOffset for another DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have an web api that return events. Each event occurs at a given date which is abstracted as a DateTimeOffset. Now on the server I want to check if a given event has occured ***according to the event datetimeoffset, not the server datetimeoffset***.

For example an event has datetimeoffset 2014-02-06 10:00:00+0300, server is datetimeoffset 2014-02-06 10:00:00+0100. How can I check if the event has already happened?

Comment: What about converting the event time to UTC and comparing with `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could just compare the two `DateTimeOffset` directly. Or, you could use the `UtcDateTime` property to get the UTC value of the `DateTimeOffset` and use that for comparison.

**Example:**

```
var eventTime = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 2, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
var serverTime = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 2, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
var otherTime = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 2, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(-1));

Console.WriteLine("\tLocalTime\t\t\tUtcTime\t\tInThePast");
Console.WriteLine("Server\t{0}\t{1}",serverTime, serverTime.UtcDateTime);
Console.WriteLine("Event\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", eventTime, eventTime.UtcDateTime, eventTime < serverTime);
Console.WriteLine("Other\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", otherTime, otherTime.UtcDateTime, otherTime < serverTime);
```

**Would produce:**

```
        LocalTime                       UtcTime                 InThePast
Server  2/6/2014 10:00:00 AM +01:00     2/6/2014 9:00:00 AM
Event   2/6/2014 10:00:00 AM +03:00     2/6/2014 7:00:00 AM     True
Other   2/6/2014 10:00:00 AM -01:00     2/6/2014 11:00:00 AM    False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Offset Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.offset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) which returns a [TimeSpan object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) within a range from -14 hours to 14 hours.

Having that property, you could easily compute if an event is already happened.